# How do I solve such Matrix problems in Linear Algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I was given a problem in which a matrix $A$ was specified along with its determinant value, now the determinant of another matrix $B$ was asked to be found out whose indices were scalar multiplies of $A$. What I did was to factor out the scalar from the matrix and substitute the value of matrix $A$. However to my great surprise I found out that each row had to be factored out and the scalars would be indexed to its power by the number of rows and then the determinant operation be applied. This is something that took me aback and left me absolutely confused. I am looking for a clear cut and elimination by contradiction (yet trivial) explanation to this.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by this.  Can you give a simple example?

Comment: It's hard to follow your description, but I appreciate you including your thoughts on it. Could you provide the question itself, or was it on an exam paper you no longer have access to?

Comment: Is this your question?  Given matrix ${\bf A}$ (and thus $\det {\bf A}$), and ${\bf B} = \alpha {\bf A}$ for some unknown scalar $\alpha$, find $\det {\bf B}$.  Please clarify!

Comment: Is it $\det(\lambda A)  =\lambda^n \det A$?

Comment: $$\[
 \begin{matrix}
  1 & 3 & 0 \\
  2 & 6 & 4 \\
  -1 & 0 & 2
 \end{matrix}
\]$$ Lets assume this is A.Whose determinant value is -12.Now B is$$ \[
 \begin{matrix}
  2 & 6 & 0 \\
  4 & 12 & 8 \\
  -2 & 0 & 4
 \end{matrix}
\]$$.I am asked to find the determinant value of B.

Answer (score 1):

One of the basic properties of determinants that you should have learned is that they are multilinear functions of the columns (or rows) of a matrix. Indeed, some treatments start with this and a few additional properties as the definition of a determinant and then derive from them the formulas that you’re likely familiar with.

Specifically, if $A_i$ denotes the $i$th column of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$, then (with a slight abuse of notation) we can write $\det A = \det(A_1,\dots,A_n)$. The multilinearity property says among other things that for every $1\le k\le n$, $$\det(A_1,\dots,cA_k,\dots,A_n)=c\det(A_1,\dots,A_k,\dots,A_n).$$ That is, multiplying a single column of $A$ by $c$ multiplies its determinant by $c$ as well. With $cA$, you’ve multiplied *every* column of $A$ by $c$, therefore $\det(cA)=c^n\det(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

As a brief example, consider

$$\begin{align}A&=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}\\[10 pt]
\det(A)&=ad-bc \\[10pt]
B&=nA \\[10 pt]
&=\begin{pmatrix}na & nb\\ nc& nd\end{pmatrix} \\[10 pt]
\det(B)&=nand-nbnc \\[10pt]
&=n^2ad-n^2bc\\[10 pt]
&=n^2(ad-bc)\\[10 pt]
&=n^2\det(A)
\end{align}
$$
In general this is true: for an $p$-dimensional matrix, $\det(nA)=n^p\det(A)$. This is because we multiply together $p$ values from the matrix when computing the determinant, and thus we pick up $p$ copies of $n$. I suggest playing around with this idea if you are still confused.

Comment: Alright but do I apply the determinant first or do I perform the matrix operation first?

Comment: If you already know $\det(A)$ and just want $\det(B)$, simply multiply $\det(A)$ by the scalar multiple to the power of the dimension of your matrix. Otherwise, it doesn't matter. You can multiply through by $n$ and then take the determinant, or you can take the determinent and multiply by $n^p$.

Comment: but why should 2*(-12) fail? Where am I getting wrong.If I just take the determinant on both sides and substitute values what is the problem.There I will be factoring only one 2 out of the determinant.

Comment: You cannot factor a scalar multiple out of a determinant. The operation applies to that scalar multiple as well.